# Pop up stage with opaque background in html

Tags: html, css

I need to create a popup [like the map has here on this page](http://cleveland.citysearch.com/profile/603358712/willoughby_oh/meineke_car_care_center.html), but I'm not sure how best to do it and wondered if anyone could point me to some code would match that effect?

Any ideas would be great.

Comment: Don't you just love it when you get three answers in 7 minutes?

Comment: Ha ha yes, most definitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Twitter Bootstrap modal jQuery plugin is really nice. You can get the html and javascript for it by customizing bootstrap here: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html

select only Modals from the components section and modals from the jQuery plugins section, and nothing else. Then download.

How to use it can be found here:

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

basically what you do is in your markup, make a div that will be the popup, and give it the classes "modal hide fade". And then make something that will be the button to toggle the modal, and give it the attributes data-target="(the css selector of the modal div)" and data-toggle="modal".

Comment: Great stuff, thank you very much. Can I change the popup effects on it, ie not coming down from the top?

Comment: but that should be easy; just change the positioning of the hidden div in the css file.

Comment: other than that, the great thing about the bootstrap modal is that you only have to write html, no js, to make modals.

Answer (score 0):

To create a basic dialog/modal, you just need to create a new `div` or show an existing `div` with `position: fixed` and `z-index: 1000` (or some other high value) using JavaScript. That `div` can have whatever contents you like. Along with the dialog/modal div, you would probably want a backdrop `div` as well, probably with at least the following styling:

```
position: fixed;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
z-index: 500; // or some other high value
```

If you don't want to create your own, you could take a look at [jQuery UI dialogs](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) or [bootstrap modals](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I hadn't seen these before I accepted as it was right, they're all good so thanks for the replies and I'll probably make one myself.

Comment: @ig13 if you find his answer being the best, you can still accept it instead of the other one.